# AttributeError at / 'str' object has no attribute 'get' in Danjo

Tags: python-3.x, django

Exception Value:'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Exception Location: C:\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py, line 346, in _get_validation_exclusions

models.py

from django.db import models

class HomePageModel(models.Model):

```
first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 20) 
last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
password = models.CharField(max_length = 12)
confirm_password = models.CharField(max_length = 12)
phone_number = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
gender = models.CharField(max_length = 6)
city = models.CharField(max_length = 20)

def __str__(self): 
    return self.first_name
```

forms.py

from django import forms
from .models import HomePageModel
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
import re

class HomePageForm(forms.ModelForm):

```
class Meta:
    model = HomePageModel
    fields = "__all__"

def clean(self):
    super(HomePageForm, self).clean()
    first_name = self.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
    try:
        regex = re.compile('[@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:]')
        flag_decimal = 0
        flag_alpha = 0
        if len(first_name) > 20:
            raise ValidationError('Fisrt Name can not be more than 20 characters')
        if (regex.search(first_name) != None):
            raise ValidationError('Fisrt Name can not have a special character')
        else:
            for char in first_name:
                if char.isdecimal():
                    flag_decimal = 1
                if char.isalpha():
                    flag_alpha = 1
            if flag_decimal == 1 or flag_alpha == 0:
                raise ValidationError('Fisrt Name can not have a number')
        return first_name
    except ValidationError as e:
        print(e)
```

.... #rest validation

views.py

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import HomePageForm

def home_page(request):

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = HomePageForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponse('Successful')
    else:
        return render(request, "home.html", {'form':form})
else:
    form = HomePageForm()
    return render(request, "home.html", {'form':form})
```

template

```
<body>
    <h2>Home Page</h2>
    <form action = "" method = "POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
        {%csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value='Submit'> 
    </form> 
</body>
```

Please help me to fix this error.
Thanks !

Comment: you should post your code not that way. They are code displayed in normal view

Answer (score 0):

try to change the name of the function in your forms from clean to clean_first_name

Comment: i guess this won't work. I tried though, received below error
'super' object has no attribute 'clean_first_name'

Comment: can you edit your question and mention the error above so I can see it clearly

Comment: I am not sure why its showing exception location as myenv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py.
Not any of my py files

Comment: those are the files which are coming with django

Comment: Exactly, i am not getting any error message for my coded files. bdw i don't see any edit option to change the view.

Comment: you should edit your question and include the top parts of the codes to the code secments as an example these are not seen as codes: from django import forms from .models import HomePageModel from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError import re

class HomePageForm(forms.ModelForm):